# Jquery - Ajax displaying the content of DIV from the result of a Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am having a problem displaying the content of a DIV after I have run a Jquery/Ajax call. The call runs a MySQL query and returns a 0 or a 1 depending on the query result.

What I am trying to do is to display the content of the div "#availability_1" if the query result is 1. I have temp alert in my code which does display the query result, in my test the result is 1.

I have  in the code but nothing is displayed. Can anyone see where I am going wrong.

```
$( function() {
$( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
$("#ToTime").on("change",function(){
var date1=$("#datepicker1").val();
var date2=$("#datepicker2").val();
var time1=$("#FromTime").val();
var time2=$("#ToTime").val();
console.log(date1);
console.log(date2);
console.log(time1);
console.log(time2);
  $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"check_booked_advert.php",
        data: {
            FromDate:date1,
            ToDate:date2,
            FromTime:time1,
            ToTime:time2,
        },
            success:function(data){
                alert(data);
            if(data==0){
                $("#availability_1").html("Dates available");
            }
            else{
                $("#availability_1").html("Date overlap!");
            }
        }
     });

});
});
```

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: what will exact `data value` and what message print in div

Comment: Is the query you're "Posting" with the route handler at "check_booked_advert.php" an INSERT statement or a SELECT statement?

Comment: @lopezdp  hi, its a simple SELECT statement and in testing it does return the value I am expecting which is "1".

Comment: @Bhargav Hi the data value returned is "1" and the message I want to display "Date overlap!" as per the code above.

Comment: so whats wrong if 1 than message should be `data overlap`

Comment: where is `#availability_1` div define share

Comment: @Bhargav  hi, #availability_1 div is in the HTML part of the code, <div id="#availability_1"></div>

Comment: remove # from id="#availability_1" and check

Comment: @Bhargav  well spotted. This is the classic case of anoth set of eyes. Many thanks.

Comment: @Bhargav if you have time change your well spotted comment into an answer and I will mark it as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `#` from `div id="#availability_1"`

so it will work

```
<div id="availability_1"></div> //remove #
```

no need in `# in id its simple name`

Answer (score 1):

Since you have created a SELECT statement in your route handler, then you need to effectively "GET" the data that you are querying from your database.

Your AJAX call type is currently set to "POST".

Try changing the AJAX call type as follows and see if it helps:

```
$.ajax({
        type:"get",
        url:"check_booked_advert.php",
        data: {
            FromDate:date1,
            ToDate:date2,
            FromTime:time1,
            ToTime:time2,
        },
            success:function(data){
                alert(data);
            if(data==0){
                $("#availability_1").html("Dates available");
            }
            else{
                $("#availability_1").html("Date overlap!");
            }
        }
     });
```

Comment: Wanna create a code pen and share more of the code?

Comment: What does your query look like? Try to add some more info to the question regarding how to recreate your issue and Ill take a look and help out.